# Inserting two NULLs values into an UNIQUE column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, null, java, unique-constraint

I use: `sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar`

Error received:

> ```
> SQLite_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE] A UNIQUE constraint failed: companies.ncf
> ```

I ask a few things to the user, there is two fields that are optional to complete but, if those fields have data, they need to be **unique** on the entire database. If the user leaves both empty, finishes completing the form, and clicks the *Save* button, this is when I receive the error mentioned above.

Data to insert:

```
company_id: (empty) (auto increment)
name:       WebServices Inc.
postal:     56585
rnc:        (null)
ncf:        (null)
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
    company_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name                TEXT    NOT NULL,
    postal              INTEGER,
    rnc                 TEXT    UNIQUE,
    ncf                 TEXT    UNIQUE
);
```

Code to insert (I receive the error with this):

```java
String sql =    "INSERT INTO companies "
                + "(name, postal, rnc, ncf) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pstm.setString(1, company.getName());
            pstm.setInt(2, company.getPostal());
            pstm.setString(3, company.getRnc());
            pstm.setString(4, company.getNcf());
            pstm.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "SQLException", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

I tried (I receive the error with this too):

```java
    // Java 7 try-with-resources
    try (Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pstm.setString(1, company.getNombre());
        pstm.setInt(2, company.getPostal());

        if (company.getRnc() != "") {
            pstm.setString(3, company.getRnc());
        } else {
            pstm.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        }

        if (company.getNcf() != "") {
            pstm.setString(4, company.getNcf());
        } else {
            pstm.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        }

        pstm.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "SQLException", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

A document from SQLite about [NULL Handling in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) says that:

> This involved making NULLs indistinct for the purposes of the SELECT
>   DISTINCT statement and for the UNION operator in a SELECT. NULLs are
>   still distinct in a UNIQUE column.

This means that we can insert multiple values to a `UNIQUE` column in a table because NULLs are distinct. So, why I do get the error?

StackTrace:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE]  A UNIQUE constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: empresas.ncf)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:825)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:863)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:99)
    at databaseTier.TransactionEmpresa.insert(TransactionEmpresa.java:210)
    at presentationTier.FormularioEmpresa$1.actionPerformed(FormularioEmpresa.java:199)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I would suggest that _empty_ is not the same as _null_.  Are you absolutely sure that _null_ was trying to be inserted into the column when the user left the data _empty_?  Can you set up a test scenario with a table that does not have the unique constraint and have the user leave the data _empty_ and see what winds up in the table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I used `Statement` and the query `VALUES ('example', ' ', null, null)` and it worked!. I tried to print the SQL but, I didn't get nothing printed. I used SQLiteStudio and I tried the query and also worked. If I change the query to `VALUES ('example', ' ', ' ', ' ')` doesn't work anymore because there is two empty values and on a column only must exist 1 empty value, another empty value will be a repeated value. So, this brings us to the way that I'm using to insert a `NULL` value to the database, which is not working. Is not entering the `NULL` value at all, apparently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73956/discussion-between-ypercube-and-robert-gomez).